# Generate Random String in Postman

Tags: postman

I'm new at postman an im trying to generate a random string with letters(A-Z) and numbers(0-9). The string should have 20 points. I don't know how to set the Body and the pre req. I know that the Request must be POST. I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 20):

You can add scripts to the `Pre-request Script` to create this value.

This function will create the random value from the characters in the `dataset` and it will be 20 characters in length - The length can be adjusted when calling the function with your desired min and max values.

```js
function randomString(minValue, maxValue, dataSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {
    if (!minValue) {
        minValue = 20;
        maxValue = 20;
    }

    if (!maxValue) {
        maxValue = minValue;
    }

    let length = _.random(minValue, maxValue),
        randomString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        randomString += dataSet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dataSet.length));
    return randomString;
}

pm.variables.set('randomString', randomString());
```

Adding a basic body like this is how you can use the randomly generated value:

```json
{
    "randomValue": "{{randomString}}"
}
```

When the request is sent, it will execute the function in the `Pre-request Scripts` tab and set the value as a local variable, this will then be used in the body of the request:

[image: POST Request]

Answer (score 13):

Per [postman's docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/) you should be able to use `{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}` to generate a single character. $randomPassword seems to just generate 15 random alpha numeric characters so something like:

```
{{$randomPassword}}{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}
```

should give you 20 random characters without writing much code. This is a little terse, you could also just use the $randomAlphaNumberic selector 20 times.

Comment: If "randomness" is not really important, most of time I will use the combination of $randomPassword (15) and $randomCreditCardMask (4 digits) and $randomAlphaNumeric (1 char). We can combine so we can get our desired length.

Comment: Do like that you posted the link to the docs, I managed to find a better answer, As it gives random first and last names out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

Code for your `Pre-request Script` tab in Request:

```js
    function randomString(length=1) {
        let randomString = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
            randomString += pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomAlphaNumeric}}");
        }
        return randomString;
    }
    
    STRING_LEN = 1000
    pm.variables.set('randomString', randomString(STRING_LEN));
```

Just set the `STRING_LEN` to desired value.
Test it by using expression `{{randomString}}` i.e. in URL:

```js
    https://httpbin.org/anything?string={{randomString}}
```

Result:
[image]